# WARNING Possible use of "Transverse_Mercator (Inverse transform)" projection outside its valid area

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools

I am trying to combign tiff image and shapefile and want show it. For this, I am using GeoTiff and I am stuck that my tiff file is now being displayed. Shapefile is showing properly but tiff image, which is having only 1 band and grey scale index, is not being shown because of some reason. I am getting one warning message as below.

> 2016-08-04T12:43:06.456+0530  WARNING  Possible use of "Transverse_Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
>   Latitude 180°00.0'S is out of range (±90°).

How can I remove this message?

My code is as below

```
private void displayLayers() throws Exception {
AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(this.getBlueMarble());
this.setGridCoverageReader(format.getReader(this.getBlueMarble()));

Style rgbStyle = this.createRGBStyle();

// connect to the shapefile
FileDataStore dataStore =     FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(this.getBorderShape());
SimpleFeatureSource shapefileSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource();

Style shpStyle = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.BLUE, null, 0.0f);

MapContent map = new MapContent();
map.getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(
        DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
map.setTitle("Illegal Mining");

Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(this.getGridCoverageReader(), rgbStyle);
map.addLayer(rasterLayer);

Layer shpLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileSource, shpStyle);
map.addLayer(shpLayer);

System.out.println("Trying to show on map...");
JMapPane mapPane = new JMapPane();
mapPane.setMapContent(map);
mapPane.setDisplayArea(shapefileSource.getBounds());


 //mapPane.setDisplayArea(this.getGridCoverageReader().getOriginalEnvelope());

this.add(mapPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

private Style createRGBStyle() {
GridCoverage2DReader reader = this.getGridCoverageReader();
StyleFactory sf = this.getStyleFactory();
GridCoverage2D cov = null;
try {
    cov = reader.read(null);
} catch (IOException giveUp) {
    throw new RuntimeException(giveUp);
}
// We need at least three bands to create an RGB style
int numBands = cov.getNumSampleDimensions();
System.out.println("numBands:"+numBands);
if (numBands < 3) {
    System.out.println("Bands are less than 3");

    //return null;
}
// Get the names of the bands
String[] sampleDimensionNames = new String[numBands];
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
    GridSampleDimension dim = cov.getSampleDimension(i);
    sampleDimensionNames[i] = dim.getDescription().toString();
}
final int RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2;
int[] channelNum = { -1, -1, -1 };
Boolean greyflag=false;
// We examine the band names looking for "red...", "green...",
// "blue...".
// Note that the channel numbers we record are indexed from 1, not 0.
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
    String name = sampleDimensionNames[i].toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("name :"+name);
    if (name != null) {
        if (name.matches("red.*")) {
            channelNum[RED] = i + 1;
        } else if (name.matches("green.*")) {
            channelNum[GREEN] = i + 1;
        } else if (name.matches("blue.*")) {
            channelNum[BLUE] = i + 1;
        }else if(name.matches("gray.*")){
            System.out.println("What to do here");
            channelNum[RED] = 1;
            channelNum[GREEN] = 2;
            channelNum[BLUE] = 3;
            greyflag=true;
        }
    }
}
// If we didn't find named bands "red...", "green...", "blue..."
// we fall back to using the first three bands in order
if(greyflag==false){
if (channelNum[RED] < 0 || channelNum[GREEN] < 0
        || channelNum[BLUE] < 0) {
    channelNum[RED] = 1;
    channelNum[GREEN] = 2;
    channelNum[BLUE] = 3;
}
}
// Now we create a RasterSymbolizer using the selected channels
SelectedChannelType[] sct = new SelectedChannelType[cov
        .getNumSampleDimensions()];
ContrastEnhancement ce = sf.contrastEnhancement(this.ff.literal(1.0),
        ContrastMethod.NORMALIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
    sct[i] = sf.createSelectedChannelType(
            String.valueOf(channelNum[i]), ce);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(channelNum[i]));
}

RasterSymbolizer sym = sf.getDefaultRasterSymbolizer();
ChannelSelection sel =sf.channelSelection(sct[RED]); 
if(numBands>1){
 sel = sf.channelSelection(sct[RED], sct[GREEN],
        sct[BLUE]);
}
sym.setChannelSelection(sel);

return SLD.wrapSymbolizers(sym);
}
```

I just pass two files as below code

```
public MapImagePanel() {
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 360));

this.setBlueMarble(new File("E:/tifffilename.TIFF"));

this.setBorderShape(new File("E:/shapefilename.shp"));

try {
    this.displayLayers();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This is how i use this class in main class

```
      //see output in main method
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      MapImagePanel panel = new MapImagePanel();
      panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,768));

      panel.setVisible(true);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.show();
```

Comment: Looks like you have a broken orientation. Are you specifying the dimensions in the order required (often long, lat)? Also, which version of geotools are you using?

Comment: I edited how i pass just 2 files, and I use this class.

Comment: The thing is the num of bands are less than 1, should i return null in rgbstyle? Because if i return null, even shape file which was displaying also stops displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** add the following line to your program start up:

```
System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
```

**Long Answer**

Once upon a time the GIS community decided that as computer programmers they *knew* that coordinates would be expressed as longitude,latitude pairs so they could use existing graphics code easily by treating them as a simple (x,y) pair. Then they met some geographers who politely explained that coordinates should be written as latitude, longitude, because for many years we didn't really know any longitudes and it was all a bit of a recent invention (and who knows it might not catch on).

So the computer scientists thought for a bit and said "OK, we can do that", but being lazy programmers they just changed the definition of the order **not** the code that represents the ordering. So now when your program encounters some data in `epsg:4326` it has no real way of checking if it is stored in latitude,longitude or longitude,latitude.

Thus you can get an error like:

```
Possible use of "Transverse_Mercator" projection outside its valid area. Latitude 180°00.0'S is out of range (±90°).
```

which is telling you that at some point you tried to reproject a longitude (180) when it was expecting a latitude.

I suspect most of your problem comes from forcing the map projection with:

```
map.getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(
    DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
```

when you could use either the projection of your shapefile or the coverage, which probably have the axis order (correctly) defined in their coordinate system objects.

I usually use some code like:

```
if (crs == null) {
  crs = cov.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
  System.err.println("Set CRS to " + crs);
}
if (crs == null) {
  System.err.println("No CRS defaulting to WGS84");
  crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
}

if (CRS.getAxisOrder(crs).equals(AxisOrder.EAST_NORTH)) {
  System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
}
```

to cover all eventualities with coverages.

**Even Longer Answer**

See the [GeoTools' FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) on the subject for an even fuller account and solutions.

Comment: You must be a pioneer in this field, because this was too tricky to figure out for a person like me... Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Of course, Ian invented GeoTools :-)

Comment: For this one it's mostly that I'm old (and I was at the OGC meetings that discussed the "best" way to change/fix this)